# Cannot sign in with local accounts using starterpack

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've downloaded the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts) and performed all steps as mentioned in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom). I can create accounts but if I log out and want to sign in again I always get the error invalid username or password. Can anyone share any pointers as debugging this is nearly impossible.

- I've created several accounts already just to be sure the password was ok.
- I've created the keycontainers
- I've created the two applications that are needed in the custom policies (web app and native)
- I've updated the extension file with the correct id's

Comment: turn on debugging in your policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom

Comment: ok will do, thx

Comment: Most likely, there's a problem with how you setup your IdentityExperienceFramework and/or ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework

Comment: You can’t do much wrong with that :) but you never know.

Comment: You'd be surprised. You can configure the permissions incorrectly. Register them as the wrong type of apps (one should be native client the other web api), you can input the wrong app IDs in your policy. There's many things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

yeah if you dont get your client IDS correct you cant log in and then it constantly reports as invalid credentials.

Double check that you are writing the object ids correctly.